# Assign permissions to USER not to ROLE

Tags: users

I am facing a problem and I will try to explain it here and I hope you guys can help me.

I am building a CRM in Drupal and Laravel and I have a module called Partners where I store all the information about the people that are going to work with me.

Inside partners, for now, I have the following actions:

- Create partner
- List partners
- Add users in partners

I have already created a ROLE called partner, so all the users created by the "Create Partner" page will be assigned to that role. The problem is that some partners are NOT allowed do add users, for example.

What I want is to add a custom permission to specific users based on my permissions defined inside my [`hook_permission()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_permission/7).

So for example, I have 3 permissions for now defined on my `hook_permission()`:

- Administer partners
- See all partners (the list)
- Create users in partners

And lets suppose I have 5 users assigned to the role PARTNER but I want only 3 of them to be able to create users and only 1 will be able to administer partners. This way I can use my permission by user.

I have already tried the module [User Permissions](https://drupal.org/project/user_permissions) but it is messing up with all my permissions.

Does anyone know how to do that without any workaround?

Comment: What is the version of drupal? D6?

Comment: In situations such as the one that you described I simply create new role ("Administrators", for example) and assign necessary permissions to this role. Then just add this role to users. Why don't  you create few roles and then assign them to corresponding users?

Comment: Drupal 7............

Comment: Because for Partners for example, I need at least 10 different permissions inside this role, for clients the same and so on...